# Apigee for internal microservices

Tags: security, microservices, apigee

Recently I split a big monolithic enterprise application in a bunch of microservices in CloudFoundry, that will feed Spark etc... 
Just one of them is on the edge and communicates with a service exposed externally. At this stage, we've been asked to add an additional security layer with [Apigee](https://apigee.com/about/tags/microservices). Unfortunately at this stage we cannot use oauth2 yet. 
My question is: should I use Apigee only on the edge or all the internal microservices should leverage Apigee API as well? My concern is about performance if each service calls Apigee proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the internal microservices communication, consider using Edge Microgateway instead of the standard Edge API proxy framework.The external clients will continue to route through Edge API proxy framework